# Finding MAX and MIN of random numbers

Tags: arrays, c, random, struct

I'm writing a program where the user enters numbers and the program will find MAX and MIN and the position of these numbers. I want to give the user a choice for the program to fill in the numbers for him using `rand()`.

It's working almost perfectly: the program will find the MAX number with the position but the problem occurs when printing MIN number with position -- it always prints number 8 and position 1.

Where is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct elementposition {
    int min;
    int max;
    int positionMax;
    int positionMin;
} elementposition;

int main() {
    struct elementposition minmax;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int a[500], i;
    int c = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    char y;

    printf("How many numbers you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    minmax.positionMax = minmax.positionMin = 0;

    printf("Want to fill with random numbers? (Y/N)");
    scanf(" %c", &y);

    if (y == 'Y' || y == 'y') {
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            a[i] = rand() % 10000 + 1;

            if (minmax.max < a[i]) {
                minmax.max = a[i];
                minmax.positionMax = i;
            }

            if (minmax.min > a[i]) {
                minmax.min = a[i];
                minmax.positionMin = i;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            printf("Number #%d: %d\n", i + 1, a[i]);
        }
    } else {

        printf("------------------------------------ \n");

        printf("Enter (%d) numbers: \n", c);
        scanf("%d", &a[0]);
        minmax.max = minmax.min = a[0];

        for (i = 1; i < c; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);

            if (minmax.max < a[i]) {
                minmax.max = a[i];
                minmax.positionMax = i;
            }

            if (minmax.min > a[i]) {
                minmax.min = a[i];
                minmax.positionMin = i;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nMax number is %d, number position %d. \n", minmax.max, minmax.positionMax + 1);
    printf("Min number is %d, number position %d. \n", minmax.min, minmax.positionMin + 1);

    printf("------------------------------------ \n");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You initialize `minmax.positionMax` and `minmax.positionMin`. But where do you initialize `minmax.max` and `minmax.min`? I recommend you do it when defining `minmax`, as in `struct elementposition minmax = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };`

Comment: If you just want the minimum and maximum, you don't need to store them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize `minmax.min` nor `minmax.max` in the random case. The code has undefined behavior because it depends on uninitialized values which may be anything, including trap values on some rare architectures.

You should separate the input/generation phase from the scanning phase and use a common loop for that. Also check that `c` is positive and does not exceed the length of the array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elementposition {
    int min;
    int max;
    int positionMax;
    int positionMin;
} elementposition;

int main() {
    struct elementposition minmax;
    int a[500];
    int i, count, len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    char y = 'y';

    printf("How many numbers you want to enter: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &count) != 1 || count < 1 || count > len) {
        printf("invalid count\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Want to fill with random numbers? (Y/N)");
    scanf(" %c", &y);
    if (y == 'Y' || y == 'y') {
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            a[i] = rand() % 10000 + 1;
            printf("Number #%d: %d\n", i + 1, a[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Enter (%d) numbers:\n", c);
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1) {
                printf("invalid input\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    minmax.positionMax = minmax.positionMin = 0;
    minmax.max = minmax.min = a[0];

    for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        if (minmax.max < a[i]) {
            minmax.max = a[i];
            minmax.positionMax = i;
        }
        if (minmax.min > a[i]) {
            minmax.min = a[i];
            minmax.positionMin = i;
        }
    }

    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Max number is %d, number position %d.\n", minmax.max, minmax.positionMax + 1);
    printf("Min number is %d, number position %d.\n", minmax.min, minmax.positionMin + 1);
    printf("------------------------------------\n");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `minmax.min` and `minmax.max` **before** initializing them. Here the problem for finding the min is probably that the `minmax.min` *happens* to initialy contain the value `8` and that all the values are greater.

The common way is to initialize the min to the highest possible value and max to the lowest one. As you use `int` values:

```
struct elementposition minmax = { INT_MAX, INT_MIN };
```

should be enough.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now! :)